# Is there anyway to get the user data of a running EC2 instance via AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've tried to use DescribeInstances but I've found the response result does not contain user data. Is there any way to retrieve this user data?

My usage case is I've trying to request spot instances and assign different user data to each EC2 instance for some kind of automation and then I want to tag the name of each instance according to this user data. Based on my understanding, creating a tag request requires InstanceId, which is not available at the time when I make a request to reserve a spot instance.

So I'm wondering whether there is any way to get the user data of a running instance instead of SSHing the instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DescribeInstanceAttributes endpoint will provide you with user data.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstanceAttribute.html